# How to rearrange an array according to another one?

Tags: javascript

In my visualisation in D3.js I have an initial array. It has been sorted by values from smallest to largest.

```
var firstDataset = [
  {place: "fifth", category: "A", value: 100},
  {place: "sixth", category: "C", value: 200},
  {place: "fourth", category: "B", value: 300},
  {place: "third", category: "B", value: 400},
  {place: "first", category: "A", value: 500},
  {place: "second", category: "C", value: 600}
];
```

I also have an another array. It has been sorted by property "category" from A to C.

```
var secondDataset = [
  {place: "first", category: "A", value: 1500},
  {place: "fifth", category: "A", value: 6500},
  {place: "third", category: "B", value: 3500},
  {place: "fourth", category: "B", value: 5500},
  {place: "second", category: "C", value: 2500},
  {place: "sixth", category: "C", value: 4500}
];
```

The properties "place" and "category" are the same in both cases. The values are different. How can I rearrange the second array to get the sequence of elements in it like in the first one?

Comment: So you want to sort by `place` property as in the first array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `place` and `category` property as key for the sort order with an object, which reflects the wanted order.

```js
var firstDataset = [{ place: "fifth", category: "A", value: 100 }, { place: "sixth", category: "C", value: 200 }, { place: "fourth", category: "B", value: 300 }, { place: "third", category: "B", value: 400 }, { place: "first", category: "A", value: 500 }, { place: "second", category: "C", value: 600 }],
    secondDataset = [{ place: "first", category: "A", value: 1500 }, { place: "fifth", category: "A", value: 6500 }, { place: "third", category: "B", value: 3500 }, { place: "fourth", category: "B", value: 5500 }, { place: "second", category: "C", value: 2500 }, { place: "sixth", category: "C", value: 4500 }],
    getKey = function (o) { return o.place + '|' + o.category; },
    order = Object.create(null);

firstDataset.forEach(function (o, i) {
    order[getKey(o)] = i;
});

secondDataset.sort(function (a, b) {
    return order[getKey(a)] - order[getKey(b)];
});

console.log(secondDataset);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```